# Guardar accesos de usuario en laravel

Tags: php, laravel-6

Estoy construyendo una app en laravel y me han pedido como requermiento que se guarde en la bd hora de logueo del usuario y la ip publica, se creo la tabla access con una llave foranea user_id para relacionarla con mi tabla users, tengo el siguiente metodo dentro del middleware (RedirectIfAuthenticated) dentro del if al loguearse lo redirige al home pero no me guarda registro en la bd, si pongo estas lineas en cualquier otro metodo de algun controlador funciona sin problema

```js
 public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            Access::create([
            
                'user_id'=>Auth::user()->id,
                'added_on'=>now(),
                'ip'=>$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
            ]);
            return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
          
        }
        

        return $next($request);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

si a alguno le sirve, en el controlador del login en este caso se llama LoginController en la carpeta Auth este ejecuta todos los metodos siempre y cuando se valide el user y pass por lo tanto alli debe estar la sentencia para que envie los datos a la bd, asi seria el metodo

```js
function authenticated(Request $request, $user){
        Access::create([
            
            'user_id'=>Auth::user()->id,
            'added_on'=>now(),
            'ip'=>$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
            
        
        ]);

    }
```

Comment: Por favor considera marcar tu aporte como aceptado